# Navigation Controller and UITableView Orientation issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I found a strange behavior with a UITableView when a decide to make my App compatible with landscape orientation.

I have two UITableView respectively linked to UITableViewControllers and some data.
I created a Navigation Controller linked to the first TVC and I added a segue between TVCs

I run the simulator, the first tableview appears.
I switch to Landscape mode and click on a row to view the second tableview.
I go back to Portrait Mode, and I click on the back button.

And When the first tableview re-appears, there is a strange horizontal scrolling on the bottom and I can move the tableview. It seems that the first tableview still believe to be in Landscape Mode :
[image: http://i.imgur.com/wzmFQ.png]

I tried some changes in viewWillAppear with no results...

Does anyone have encountered this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it could happend if you have a UIScrollview at the back of the UITableview. It is related to the rotation and the autolayout of the view. Check if you are setting the frame of the tableview or something  like.

Comment: I found two way to solve this problem
1. Uncheck auto-layout. But I want to use it.
2. Set the frame to : self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
in viewWillAppear method.

Comment: But I don't understand why it works with 0, 0, 200, 200 values. If you can explain me, I will apreciate it